# javascript and EMs

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering what people thought about going fully EM based? Personally I'm almost completely on board with it, font sizes, layout, media queries and all. Relating back to the users personal preferences make perfect sense.

However, when it comes to javascript it seems difficult to use anything other than pixels.

For example, if I want to add an image when the screen size is greater than a certain size, I might do this in the HTML:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 500) {
    document.write('<img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" />');
}
```

or, in the JS, I might want to change something (swap an element out, perhaps) when the screen reaches a media query break point. However I would end up with a weird mix of EMs in the CSS, and pixels in the JS, which won't match up if the users font size is anything other than default.

Does that make sense? And does anyone have any suggestions? Perhaps EM fonts and px for layout? But that loses some of the beauty of EMs.

Comment: I like your approach, is what I always use for the same reasons as you. I don't see the problem on using pixels for images (as your example), but I'll keep the ems for the layout, something that you can control with CSS media queries.

Comment: CSS media queries is the most neat solution in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, as I wrote to the other comment, this is my issue: Say my media query is worked out as the equivalent of 500px, based on the 16px default font size. If the users default font size is not 16px then the media query is not equal to 500px. So if I've got some javascript doing something at 500px, it will no longer match the media query...

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use px. You can easily calculate px-em. I recommend to read [this exhaustive article](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/) from CSS-Tricks about your issue

> The most popular method in working with em values is to set the font-size on the body to 62.5%. Because the default browser font-size is 16px, this makes it 10px (without hard-setting it to 10px, which wouldn't cascade). Using 10 as a multiplier is much easier than using 16. This way, you need a font size of 18px? Use font-size: 1.8em.
>
> So why bother with all this em business when it's just an abstraction of using pixel values anyway? Three possible reasons:
>
> 1. The ARE resizeable in IE 6
> 2. The relationship to other sizes (elastic width sites)
> 3. Em's cascade like a mo-fo
>
> The first one is the big one. If you basically want to use pixels but don't like the accessibility problems, em's may be the ticket for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is this: Say my media query is worked out as the equivalent of 500px, based on the 16px default font size, as above. If the users default font size is not 16px then the media query is not equal to 500px. So if I've got some javascript doing something at 500px, it will no longer match the media query...